# File does not exist from wacky websites?

Tags: apache, apache-log-files

Our LAMPs website has been running slow as of late, I suspect its a SQL problem but I want to check all the logs. Can somebody explain what the following log means, and give some insight if it is a performance/security problem?

```
[root@ip-10-225-131-71 logs]# tail -9 error_log
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 172.82.141.249] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.xe.com/xecurrencydata/
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 172.82.141.117] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.evite.com/gallery/category/holiday_party/
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 45.43.208.201] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.evite.com/profile/events
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 45.43.208.92] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.evite.com/gallery/category/hostess_party/
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 45.43.206.167] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.evite.com/gallery/category/brunch_lunch/
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 45.43.206.76] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.evite.com/profile/edit
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 172.82.141.55] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.xe.com/useourcontent.php
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 172.82.141.6] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.xe.com/es/
[Thu Jun 25 00:01:33 2015] [error] [client 162.213.31.80] File does not exist: /var/www/html/tt, referer: http://www.evite.com/gallery/category/birthday_milestones/
```

From my understanding, websites are trying to access files that don't exist on our webserver?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. This may be simple script-kiddie stuff- attacks from compromised computers. If that is the case, the referrer info may likely be junk and nothing to pay attention to. Do you need info on how to block these?? And what web server are we talking about? If you have a firewall, that is the best place to block these accesses.

Comment: @closetnoc If you can summarize your thoughts that would be nice, in particular if this effects performance. I am using a stock ec2 without any firewall etc. I think they set it up in 2011.

Comment: Generally, these things happen though it is annoying. It can at times continue at a rate that will effect performance enough to be concerned, but that is extremely rare. If you are seeing a lot of this, I would definitely block it. However, I do not know what EC2 consists of. If you have Apache, Nginx, or IIS, I can create some block code for the IP addresses you have. There is still a cost in processing the block, but it is a lot cheaper. If you want, post the most abusive IP addresses in your question and I can generate the code for you.

Comment: @closetnoc I don't really have a `most abusive` address. I'm using Apache. Does fail to ban prevent these guys, from loading up our server?

Comment: I do not know fail to ban though I have heard of it. I use other proprietary methods. One option is ModSecurity which is designed to stop web application attacks is likely the best there is. It is more like a firewall with HTTP packet filters.